# How to get the http dump of a website and the header both from a single curl command?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, terminal, curl, http

I have to fetch a website (multiple redirections possible using -L) and save the html content in a file named as **[HTTP_Status_code]_[Website_name].html**

Currently I am using two curl calls one for the dump and the other for header. Is there any way to club them into one?

Script:

```
cat url_list.txt | while read line; do 
if curl  -L  $line -o `curl -I $line 2>/dev/null | head -n 1 | cut -d$' ' -f2`_`basename $line`.html 
 then
   :
 else
    echo $line >>error.txt
fi 
done
```

EDIT:
I have to find the header of the last redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
cat url_list.txt | while read line; do 
if curl  -D  tmp_status.txt -L  $line -o tmp_file.html 
then
   mv tmp_file.html $(awk '/HTTP/  { print $2}' tmp_status.txt)_$(basename $line)
else
   echo $line >>error.txt
   # processing from tmp_status
fi 
done
```

- only one call of curl, but a post processing ...

Comment: Hi @Archemar , The file is being overwritten every time. So, I am getting the response of last url only but I want response of each url. So, Can you please suggest me ?

Comment: strange .. both tmp_ sould be updated for every curl call. maybe `rm tmp_status.txt` before if ?

Comment: Hi@ArchemarIf I do so then I need to manually save the response in text file then it will take a lot of time and I need response of One million sites. What exactly I needed is; I want url's name under text file named their response i.e there are 100 url's whose response is 200 OK in the last redirection(If there is any redirection) then i need a text file named 200 in which these 100 url's will be there whose last response is 200 OK. But your code is doing something else.

Comment: Hey @Archemar : Do you know how to do this?

Comment: I have done it :)